# htaccess RewriteRule problem

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with RewriteRules.

I'm currently using this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?clip=$1
```

This works fine for links as these, where `$_GET['clip']` is the value after the slash:

http://example.com/abcdefg

But not for those with a dot character, like these:

http://example.com/abcdefg.png

How should I change the RewriteRule to make it work for such links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?clip=$1
```

i wouldn't suggest this technique because it will cause an extra disk read to check if the file is there...
if you have the possibility i would advise to organize your directory structure in a way that apache can tell from the directory what to do. example from my framework:

```
  # skip whitelisted directories
  RewriteRule ^(test|skin|stylesheets|images|javascripts|favicon|robots\.txt|index\.php) - [L]
  RewriteRule ([-_\w\/]*) index.php?p=$1 [NE,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?clip=$1
```

This will prevent it from ignoring files that are really on your server. so `http://example.com/abcdefg.png` will work, as long as `/abcdefg.png` exists.

Also the regex you used in the rewrite rule needs to be altered slightly, I removed the `.` as you were preventing it.

Comment: Read the comment I added to nhnb. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are matching on any string that does not contain "/" or ".". If you want the match to include the extension, you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$
```

If you don't care about it:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)
```

Comment: This together with jordanstephens answer makes perfect. Thanks!