# .htaccess RewriteRule path to query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to achieve that a url like

example.com/**path1** to example.com/index.php?p1=**path1**

example.com/**path1**/**path2** to example.com/index.php?p1=**path1**&p2=**path2**

In my .htaccess I have:

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?c=$1&g=$2 [NC,L]`

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ /index.php?g=$1 [NC,L]`

It works well for the case where we have the example.com/**path1**/**path2** but for the the case example.com/**path1** only works if there is no dot in the url. For example, I want to example.com/mydomain.com working to example.com/index.php?g=domain.com but I am not able to make it working.

Could you help me with this please?

Comment: with `([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)` you are explicitly only handling the case of alpha-numeric plus underscores. That would exclude your sample case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess RewriteRule problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430693/htaccess-rewriterule-problem)

Answer (score 7):

here's how I would handle this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1
```

then with whatever serverside language you're using I'll use PHP parse $_GET['param'].

```
$params = explode('/', $_GET['params']);
```

Comment: You don't actually even need to pass through the `params` var on the rewrite, just pick it up with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - which makes the rule a little more succinct `RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked and I have solved this way!